# make boxes fit to containers width

Tags: css

What I'm trying to do is make the boxes inside a container auto-fit to the containers width.

```
.container{
width: 960px;
}

.box{
width: 240px; /* 960/4 = 240 */
float: left;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Is there another way to do this rather than dividing the width of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  http://jsfiddle.net/643FQ/

```
.container{
width: 960px;
}

.box{
width: 25%;
height: 50px;
float: left;
border:1px solid #000;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no shortcut for this.

The only way is using percentages or dividing the div like you are doing right now. And floating the div so they can stack on a single row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage here:

```
.box {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Please note that, since you use `1px` for your border, it'll be `2px` extras for each box, so your last box will not stack in 1 row with the other three because your `.container` is `960px`.

You can either remove the border or decrease the value of your `.box` width, or increase the width of your `.container`